# Get all methods of a class, but not those of superclasses

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

How would I get the methods of an instance of a class, but not those of its superclass?

Example:

```
class A:
    def a(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def b(self):
        pass

    def c(self):
        pass

d = B()
```

I want a way to get `b` and `c` from `d`, but not `a`. I tried using `dir(d)`, but that lists `a`, `b` and `c`, not just `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) on the class itself, through the `.__class__` attribute:

```
vars(d.__class__)
```

or use [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) to retrieve the class:

```
vars(type(d))
```

This gives you a *dictionary* (specifically, a `mappingproxy`), you can always just get the names by calling `list()` on it:

```
>>> vars(type(d))
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'b': <function B.b at 0x1028a7378>, 'c': <function B.c at 0x103168598>, '__doc__': None})
>>> list(vars(type(d)))
['__module__', 'b', 'c', '__doc__']
```